# Internationalization and localization in Rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I am trying to wrap my head around what localization means here. I've been reading these [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html):

> Internationalization is a complex problem. Natural languages differ in
>   so many ways (e.g. in pluralization rules) that it is hard to provide
>   tools for solving all problems at once. For that reason the Rails I18n
>   API focuses on:
>
> providing support for English and similar languages out of the box
>   making it easy to customize and extend everything for other languages
>   As part of this solution, every static string in the Rails framework -
>   e.g. Active Record validation messages, time and date formats - has
>   **been internationalized, so localization of a Rails application means
>   "over-riding" these defaults.**

What does that mean? What does localization mean here?

I think this makes sense:

> The default en.yml locale in this directory contains a sample pair of
>   translation strings:
>
> en:   hello: "Hello world" This means, that in the :en locale, the key
>   hello will map to the Hello world string. Every string inside Rails is
>   internationalized in this way, see for instance Active Model
>   validation messages in the activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml
>   file or time and date formats in the
>   activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml file. You can use YAML
>   or standard Ruby Hashes to store translations in the default (Simple)
>   backend.
>
> The I18n library will use English as a default locale, i.e. if you
>   don't set a different locale, :en will be used for looking up
>   translations.

Answer (score 1):

In the bolded statement,

**validations have been "internationalized"** (read: supports customization for localisation)

**so localization of a Rails applica....** (read: the activity of localising your application is by means of overriding the default values provided by the built in internationalization functionality.)

Will revise my answer if it doesn't help.